# ¿Utilizando SendGrid V1 y C# como obtengo los correos inválidos por rango de fechas?

Tags: c#, .net

Tengo el siguiete codigo:

```
var response = client.RequestAsync(method: SendGridClient.Method.GET, urlPath: "suppression/invalid_emails/").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

donde obtengo todos los correos invalidos registrados en SendGrid hasta la fecha actual, pero quiero obtener correos invalidos por un rango de fechas anterior...
¿Como podria enviarle parametros de fechas en la peticion y no tener que procesar despues la variable **response** ?

Answer (score 1):

Si tu versión de la API no lo soporta, siempre puedes hacer un request directo a la API REST de sendgrid, actualmente V3.

Utiliza este

GET

> https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/suppression/invalid_emails?start_time=**{start_time}**&end_time=**{end_time}**&limit=10&offset=0

HTTP/1.1

Y esto te daría una respuesta como

HTTP/1.1 200

```
[
  {
    "created": 1449953655,
    "email": "user1@example.com",
    "reason": "Mail domain mentioned in email address is unknown"
  },
  {
    "created": 1449939373,
    "email": "user1@example.com",
    "reason": "Mail domain mentioned in email address is unknown"
  }
]
```

Claro esta que para poderla usar necesitas estar previamente autenticado con la API por lo que en el header de Beaerer token debes colocar tu API KEY.

Comment: Regalame un ejemplo de start_time y end_time... para revisar el formato.
Gracias por la respuesta.